# testing backbone views with Jasmine-node

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, backbone.js

I'm trying to test my backbone view using jasmine-node, and i'm facing a problem with Jquery when i run the unit tests.

backbone View

```
var Backbone = require("Backbone"),
    $ = require('jquery');
    Template = require("mytemplate");
    Backbone.$ = $;

module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({// my view ...});
```

test

```
 var Backbone       = require("Backbone"),
    MyView  = require("MyView");

 //specs ....
```

The problem is:

My view works great :).  but when i run the tests it says "**jQuery requires a window with a document**". I've tried to use jsdom but it did'n work for me :(

is it possible to run jquery inside jasmine-node ?

also, i'm using gulp with webpack

thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

Views require a document in order to be functional, so it makes more sense to test them in the closest thing to the actual environment they live in (e.g. a web browser or a headless browser)

Not sure about gulp, but for grunt, https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine is a great plugin

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use another lib called [`jsdom`](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) it mocks the window object to be used by jquery.

called the below on top of every test suite (i just wrapped it in a module and require it on top everytime).

```
global.window = require("jsdom")
                  .jsdom()
                  .parentWindow;
global.document = window.document;
```

But i personally still not the recommended this method, i prefer the [`phantomJs`](http://phantomjs.org/) approach :)

Comment: Hey thanks for you help but this didn't work :( it says that the HTML object has no method createWindow.

Comment: which jsdom package did u used? (npm instal xxxx?)

Comment: I have this in package.json "jsdom": "^1.0.0-pre.3"

Comment: can u try again like edited above? im using 2.0.0. The document > https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom